# VS C# 2010, debug(f5) shows older version of code buil(f6) runs correct code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I haven't been able to find a working solution online for this problem. 
Maybe because I'm using the express edition?
But when I for example add a button to my form en press f5 It does not appear. But when building with f6 I works fine.

Does it have anything to do with pointing it in the right direction via "directory's containing source code? ifso where should it point to?

or is it something else alltogether?

hope someone can help. I've run into other related question from other programmers but without working solutions..

thnx in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try going to Tools->Options

Then select the Project & Solutions Catagory, find the sub-catagory 'Build and Run' and change the 'Only build startup projects and dependencies on Run' if it's selected.

It might be in a slightly different place, this is the VS2008 location but it is similar.

Comment: nice! thnx it worked, i changed the settings below to always build. now i can finally debug again :)

Answer (score 0):

Try right clicking on the Solution and running the Clean command, then rebuilding:
[image]

Comment: That option doesn't show in my list. maybe cause I have Express edition?